# Fiori with Github How to hide service address

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I want to upload a SAP Fiori app as public in Github, but I need to hide service address.

So I thought I could do it putting host address in manifest.json (or metadata.xml) in a separated file and using it in .gitignore.

I've tryied to put it in a separated file and put it in .gitignore, but didn't get it to work cause application did not run when I tryied run it and it gave me error with this separated file.

Is that a way of doing it ?

Comment: or the other way around, add `manifest.json` to to `.gitignore` and provide a sanitised `manifest.example.json`, which is usually how that is done with `.env` files.

Comment: Hi! I could not understand. Can you give an example like manifest.example.json will have something or something else ?